# How to change value in csv column by value from another file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a post-processing CSV file. Example of my file:

```
serial_number1, name_number_ID1, price1, state1
serial_number2, name_number_ID1, price2, state2
serial_number3, name_number_ID2, price1, state3
serial_number4, name_number_ID3, price1, state4
...
```

So I have a repeated name in columns. In another file, I have an alias for sample name, and the file looks that:

```
NAME_NUMBER_ID; Alias; Data; NrOfOfert
name_number_ID1; Name1; XX; YY
name_number_ID2; Name2; XX; YY
name_number_ID3; Name3; XX; YY
```

Now I need to change NameID in the first file on Alias from second file.

Result file would be:

```
    serial_number1, Name1, price1, state1
    serial_number2, Name1, price2, state2
    serial_number3, Name2, price1, state3
    serial_number4, Name3, price1, state4
    ...
```

What would be the best way to read the first file (hundreds of record) and replace the nameID to proper Alias? Should I create a dictionary? Sometimes I have too many Alias to do it manually.

Could someone lead me to the most optimal solution?

EDIT: I just created a dictionary from the second file, and use it:

```
def.replace({def.iloc[:,1]:dictionary})
```

Thanks for answers, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use pandas and import read_csv. Import only the columns you need and then merge the DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
# For selecting cols you can use keys or col names
df1 = pd.read_csv(infile1, usecols=[0,3])
df2 = pd.read_csv(infile2, usecols=[1,2])

# Merge data set 1 and 2
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Comment: I tried to do that by ur solution. The problem is: I have only a few aliases and much more ID's in the first file. I mean, as I wrote in the first file, two first rows have the same nameID(1), but in alias file, i have only one Alias. Resume: hundreds of records and only a few aliases. That's why i asked about a dictionary. :C

Comment: How is the data linked? Do they both have the same 'name_number_ID'?

Comment: Data in the first file is not related. In second file (alias) first column is NameID used in the first file, the second column is value to which the NameID in the first file should be swapped. I just need to change the value in col[1] in the first file. according to the file with aliases. So if in first file in the second column is XXX, and in alias file, I have a XXX : YYY i need to change XXX in frist file to YYY. 
SO:In first file i have an only ID of the product name. NameID can be the same in few records. All i need to do is pick find sameID from AliasFile and replace it to Name column.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel ready to use pandas for this, you could probably have python replace line by line. Pandas is really built for this, so it's the better option.

This example should get the change started, but it would need some changes to actually work.

```
#open all necessary files
with open('infile.csv', 'r') as infile, open('namefile.csv', 'r') as namefile,
    open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:

    #iterate over both input files
    for in_line, name_line in zip(infile, namefile):
        #collect the row's information
        out_ls = in_line.split(', ')
        #collect the name
        name = name_line.split('; ')[1]
        #replace the id with the name
        out_ls[1] = name
        #print out the line
        outfile.write(', '.join(out_ls))
```

If you use this code, watch that the line numbers match (so header's don't get in the way and there aren't more lines in one file than the other forcing the program to end early). This implementation does avoid storing the whole column or file by the program by writing the corrected portion line-by-line. Good luck!